# Jquery doing two calculations

Tags: jquery

I'm wanting to divide then multiply but not sure how to do both ideas?

It's working but it's just dividing at the moment.

```
<input type="text" value="0" class="fuel" id="fuel"/>
<span id="total">0ml</span>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#fuel').keyup(function(){
jQuery('#total').text(jQuery('#fuel').val()  / 3000 * 1000);
});   
});
```

Comment: It is not clear what the current result is vs the wanted result.  We need a fully reproducible example and also what you expect and what you are getting.

Comment: I've adding in the html sorry, the current code only divides by 3000, but I'm wanting to multiply after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse your `jQuery('#fuel').val()` to int for example.
 `.val()` returns a string (check this jQuery documentation about `.val()`: [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)
For better understanding of javascript parse functions check this: [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#fuel').keyup(function(){
jQuery('#total').text(parseInt(jQuery('#fuel').val())  / 3000 * 1000);
//up we use parseInt function to convert string to a number
});   
});
```

Comment: That's working now thanks!! How do I round the answer to 2 decimal places to tidy it up?

Comment: jQuery('#total').text((parseInt(jQuery('#fuel').val())  / 3000 * 1000).toFixed(2));

Comment: Use `toFixed()` for number of decimal places: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Answer (score 0):

Replace `jQuery('#fuel').val()` to `parseInt(jQuery('#fuel').val())`